# 500 error when trying to upload from Meteor using slingshot package

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-cloud-storage, meteor-slingshot

I am using the following Meteor Package

https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot

I have a javascript file in the server side that looks like this

```
Slingshot.GoogleCloud.directiveDefault.GoogleSecretKey = Assets.getText('google-cloud-service-key.pem');


Slingshot.createDirective("myFileUploads", Slingshot.GoogleCloud, {
  bucket: "enwave",
  GoogleAccessId: "randomID",

 authorize: function () {
   //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.
   if (!this.userId) {
     var message = "Please login before posting files";
     throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
   }

   return true;
 },

 key: function (file) {

   //Store file into a directory by the user's username.
   var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
   return user.username + "/" + file.name;
 }
});
```

I have this on my client side

```
'change #fileUpload':function(event, template){
      //evt.preventDefault();
      var file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
      console.log(file);

      var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");
      uploader.send(document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0], function (error, downloadUrl) {
      Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$push: {"profile.files": downloadUrl}


      });

      });

    }
```

I have this in my lib folder

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions("myFileUploads", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB (use null for unlimited)
});
```

and in /private folder I have a google-cloud-service-key.pem file that I converted after downloading from google cloud.

I get this error when choosing a image in the file upload input

```
 POST https://enwave.storage.googleapis.com/ 500 (OK)
debug.js:41 update failed: Access denied
```

I must be doing something wrong, google says a 500 error in google cloud is a internal server error, but I must be doing something wrong, I highly doubt it is on googles end. I am also testing off of localhost if that might be it.

Thanks in Advance for any help.

After log the error in the console, this is what I get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pffI4.png

This is the XML Response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>InternalErrorWe encountered an internal error. Please try again. ABCemsqA/49FPwB5u877Jt1vyodMFYvQo+Nxba9L+54t4n31W5StGcfiL1/DfhrzuGEfhi63U6j3 5WYQxoYPL5T9xNaFkuX9Hg...
```

This is what the headers return

```
Remote Address:74.125.25.132:443
Request URL:https://enwave.storage.googleapis.com/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 OK
Request Headers
:authority:enwave.storage.googleapis.com
:method:POST
:path:/
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
content-length:59584
content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
origin:http://localhost:3000
referer:http://localhost:3000/submit
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
x-client-data:CI62yQEIpLbJAQiptskBCMS2yQEI6ojKAQieksoBGKuJygE=
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

minimize.jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bucket"

enwave
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Disposition"

inline; filename="minimize.jpeg"
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="GoogleAccessId"

00b4903a977a9b1f9ad3c9f1f3785afdc1af228104554ee6fce967a7899eb208
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

eyJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbWyJjb250ZW50LWxlbmd0aC1yYW5nZSIsMCw1ODEyMl0seyJrZXkiOiJtaW5pbWl6ZS5qcGVnIn0seyJidWNrZXQiOiJlbndhdmUifSx7IkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSI6ImltYWdlL2pwZWcifSx7IkNvbnRlbnQtRGlzcG9zaXRpb24iOiJpbmxpbmU7IGZpbGVuYW1lPVwibWluaW1pemUuanBlZ1wiIn1dLCJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0wMi0xOVQxNzoxNzoxMy43MThaIn0=
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

QmiNNCDxvbYvZ8X27dCsj4OjvSj4zzIcb3pWuo6qP+10mo9TkaUTgc1Su8EbAW04OtZtZr2Uiohf8S5bIiEqbUBQS8bknFszysTvTQSSOD4DsZM6dNP6iZ5Ukd9Qboc3aoAH5WOJCKxRnxJVdOM6NTr4W5V5SSXtgooHKWrOTIA=
------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="minimize.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryjW0KMAtnvqnxsY7u--
Response Headers
access-control-allow-origin:*
access-control-expose-headers:Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=0.08
content-length:5196
content-type:application/xml; charset=UTF-8
date:Thu, 19 Feb 2015 17:12:14 GMT
server:UploadServer ("Built on Feb 9 2015 19:54:00 (1423540440)")
status:500
```

Comment: Check if the `error` is set in the even callback.

uploader.send(document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0], function (**error**, downloadUrl) {
      **console.log(error);**

Comment: @Soren It seems to be where the error is happening, but I am not sure if the log in the console shows anymore info. I posted the image above.

Comment: That is different than the error I had.   It looks to be related to the googleapi, however I'm not familiar with googles cloud service, so not able to help.

Comment: This is being denied by google, not slingshot. So there might be something wrong with your bucket setup. Check what kind of response you get when that POST is sent out in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: @d_inevitable I added the post header info above.